# Ember.js - how to pass an array or a model from the controller to the template?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm getting two errors with the code I have below.  I'm not sure how to go about fixing it.  It looks like #each is looking for a promise to be returned rather then a model or an array.  Am I right?  If yes, how can I have it to take an array or a model?  Thanks.

> Error 1. **Assertion failed: The value that #each loops over must be an
>   Array. You passed [object Object] ember.js:3231**
>
> Error 2. **Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method
>   'addArrayObserver'**

### Controller

```
var StudentBooksController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    needs: ['application','request'],

    selectedBooks: function() {
        //return an array here such as [1, 3, 5, 7]
    }.property(),
    studentList: function() {
        return this.store.find('student');
    }.property(),
    filteredStudentBooks: function() {
        var self = this;

        // I tried "return []" here and no error on the console.

        return self.get('studentList').then(function (students){           
            // I tried "return []" here and it still gave me the same error on console.

            return self.get('selectedBooks').then(function(sb){
                var aList = students.get('content');
                aList.forEach(function(al){
                    al.set('hasAccess', _.contains(sb, sb.get('id') ));
                    console.log(_.contains(sb, sb.get('id') ));
                });

                return aList;
            });
        })
    }.property('selectedBooks','studentList')
});

export default StudentBooksController;
```

### Route

```
//----- Nothing in the Route file ---
```

### Template

```
    {{#each filteredStudentBooks}}
        // do something here such as printing the name
        {{name}}
        {{#if hasAccess}}
            User has access.
        {{else}}
            User doesn't have access.
        {{/if}}
    {{/each}}
```

### **SOLUTION**

With @kingpin2k's help, here is the solution I ended up with.

```
    filteredStudentBooks: function() {
    var self = this, 
        resp = [];           

    self.get('studentList').then(function (students){           
        // I tried "return []" here and it still gave me the same error on console.

        self.get('selectedBooks').then(function(sb){
            var aList = students.get('content');

            var sortedStudentList = aList.sortBy('name');
            aList = sortedStudentList ;

            aList.forEach(function(al){
                al.set('hasAccess', _.contains(sb, sb.get('id') ));
                console.log(_.contains(sb, sb.get('id') ));
                resp.pushObject(al);
            });                              

        });
    })
    return resp;
}.property('selectedBooks.[]','studentList.[]')
```

Answer (score 2):

You're returning a promise and not an array, additionally you probably should be watching the array's changing instead of just the properties.

```
filteredStudentBooks: function() {
    var self = this, 
        resp = [];


    self.get('studentList').then(function (students){           
        // I tried "return []" here and it still gave me the same error on console.

        self.get('selectedBooks').then(function(sb){
            var aList = students.get('content');

            aList.forEach(function(al){
                al.set('hasAccess', _.contains(sb, sb.get('id') ));
                console.log(_.contains(sb, sb.get('id') ));
            });

            resp.pushObjects(aList.sortBy('name').toArray());
        });
    })
    return resp;
}.property('selectedBooks.[]','studentList.[]')
```

Comment: **@kingpin2k**, thanks for your help. It works great.  I also want to sort 'resp' before returning it. I modified your answer to show what I was trying to do.  I could see the list of name in the console log to verify I was putting them to be sorted.  However, the outcome of sortFilteredResult doesn't get sorted.  What did I do wrong?

Comment: You're overriding a local reference, not the reference to the array that was returned from the functions.  See updated answer.

Comment: **@kingpin2k**, after changing to the code above, I see the object gets sorted correctly.  However, the template doesn't seem to pick up the name.  When I print out the object in the console.log, the previous one returned [Class, Class, .....]. For the current one, it prints [Array[10], ....].  Why would that break the template?

Comment: try chucking a toArray onto the end of the sortBy method

Comment: **@kingpin2k** tried with toArray() and it didn't work.  I saw 'resp' returned Array[1] > Array[10] on the console output.

I decided to do the sorting first and then do the filtering. It is now working for me with the code I modified (posted back to the question section).

Thanks a lot for helping me getting to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working solution for my question.  **@kingpin2k** gets the credit for helping most of it.  I modified the code to get the sorting and the output to return to the template.

```
filteredStudentBooks: function() {
    var self = this, 
        resp = [];           

    self.get('studentList').then(function (students){           
        // I tried "return []" here and it still gave me the same error on console.

        self.get('selectedBooks').then(function(sb){
            var aList = students.get('content');

            var sortedStudentList = aList.sortBy('name');
            aList = sortedStudentList ;

            aList.forEach(function(al){
                al.set('hasAccess', _.contains(sb, sb.get('id') ));
                console.log(_.contains(sb, sb.get('id') ));
                resp.pushObject(al);
            });                              

        });
    })
    return resp;
}.property('selectedBooks.[]','studentList.[]')
```